# Pentaho report design customize program text

Tags: pentaho

When I view my Pentaho report I want to change `Output Type` text to my own language. How can I do this?

Comment: Apparently the locale (language and others ) of your report view depend on the locale of the browser settings in which you are viewing the report.

Answer (score 0):

To change the language of PUC (Assume that you want to change on PUC) first you need to add the necessary language to the web browser so that it is presented first on the list.

Then,

i) edit PUCLogin.jsp located in `...\server\biserver-ee\tomcat\webapps\pentaho\jsp`

ii) search en_US - it can be in line 180 with the following content: `<input type="hidden" name="locale" value="en_US">` 

iii) change `"en_US"` to `"it_IT"`  (or necessary language) 

 iv) save and restart the browser and server

Hope this helps